# How can I extract unusual characters with regex statement?

Tags: regex

I have a string like this:

```
lp.xyz.com/trader/?campaign=32&p=edgetrac_100{creative}
```

how can I extract only the `100{creative}` by using regex?

Usually I'm using texts like:

```
lp.xyz.com/trader/?campaign=32&p=edgetrac_100
```

with the expression:

```
\bp=edgetrac_(?<edgetrac>+)\b
```

to only extract the 100 along with (edgetrac) to use it later like this:

```
<Read Var="destUrl1" Field='Destination URL' Regex='(\bp=edgetrac_(?{edgetrac}\w+)\b)'     />

<Map To='Value'  Condition='destUrl1 != null' Value="{destUrl1.edgetrac}" />
```

but now I need something to get the `{creative}` also, so i get `100{creative} (edgetrac)`

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see `?+` being valid in Obj-C. Could you show an example of code where this is applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I GOT IT: \bp=edgetrac_(\w+{*[a-z]*}*)

Answer (score 1):

This could help if there is nothing after *{creative}*

```
\bp=edgetrac_.*
```

or else when it has something after braces,,

```
\bp=edgetrac_(\d+){(\w+)}
```

or simply,

```
(\d+){(\w+)}
```

Then, for matching edgetrac also,

```
p=([a-zA-Z]+)_(\d+){(\w+)}
```

Here for input `lp.xyz.com/trader/?campaign=32&p=edgetrac_100{creative}`,

**\1** => edgetrac

**\2** => 100

**\3** => creative

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggestions, it may be something i could work with but let me represent my question because i think i left out some details. this is my string:  
lp.xyz.com/trader/?campaign=32&p=edgetrac_100{creative}
and I need to get something like that: 100{creative} (edgetrac)

Comment: @user1508682 : its updated in the answer above.. along with back-reference info..